# Python infinite series convergence and divergence

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I am trying to write a program that calculates the sum of the infinite series of a^n / b^(n-1) from n = 1 to infinity and terminates and raises a value error when it diverges. Here's what I have:

```
def compute_sum(a, b, tolerance=1e-5):

n=1.
computed_sum = 0.
previous_sum = 0.

while (n>0.):
    previous_sum = computed_sum
    computed_sum += a**n / b**(n-1.)
    n=n+1.
    if (computed_sum - previous_sum < tolerance or computed_sum - previous_sum < -tolerance):
        raise ValueError()       

return computed_sum
```

The loop is supposed to terminate when the difference between the computed sum and the previous is sum is less than a specified tolerance. If I deleted the if statement and computed it with a=-2 and b=3, and using a while(n<9999) I get a close answer.

I'm just not sure how to exit the loop if it diverges or the difference is less than a given tolerance level.

Am I at least headed in the right direction or is my approach completely wrong? What's the methodology here?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the absolute value `abs(...)`. You could also directly compute the value of the sum, it is `a*b/(b-a)` if `abs(a)<abs(b)`.

Comment: Now also to be found at (cross-posted to?) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526056/assertionerror-from-partial-sums-functions-in-python